# It there jquery carousel similar to mootools icarousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools, carousel

I'm looking for jquery plugin similar to http://zendold.lojcomm.com.br/icarousel/example6.asp.

I need speed-up effect for images slide like example has.

Does it exist smth similar to?

Comment: This question would be better left to google

Comment: Unfortunately couldn't find nothing similar to. It took already more than three hours...

Comment: If you need it (I will surely) I've Added the plugin version. Find it in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the jQuery UI easings:

[demo](http://jsbin.com/enaqot/2/edit)

jQuery:

```
var galW = 500; // SET HERE THE GALLERY WIDTH

var N = $('#slider img').length;

$('#thumbs img').on('click',function(){
  N = $(this).index();
  $('#slider').stop(1).animate({left: -galW*N},{duration:700, easing:'easeOutSine'});
});

// Easings:
/*
easeInQuad
easeOutQuad
easeInOutQuad
easeInCubic
easeOutCubic
easeInOutCubic
easeInQuart
easeOutQuart
easeInOutQuart
easeInSine
easeOutSine
easeInOutSine
easeInExpo
easeOutExpo
easeInOutExpo
easeInQuint
easeOutQuint
easeInOutQuint
easeInCirc
easeOutCirc
easeInOutCirc
easeInElastic
easeOutElastic
easeInOutElastic
easeInBack
easeOutBack
easeInOutBack
easeInBounce
easeOutBounce
easeInOutBounce
*/
```

If you need to handle multiple galleries on the same page or you just feel cool, here is the plugin v.

### *[PLUGIN VERSION](http://jsbin.com/epajim/edit#javascript,html,live)*

(you can customize easing, slide-time, and start-slide-*N*)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this http://css-tricks.com/creating-a-slick-auto-playing-featured-content-slider/

demo http://css-tricks.com/examples/FeaturedContentSlider/

Hope this is what you need.